# How to reduce the source of the htmlText property of the TextArea component? In Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to reduce the source htmlText of my TextArea component...but i just cant have a sucess...anyone knows how to do it ? in Flex language

> textBody.htlmText

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce the source"?

Comment: the size of the htmlText is 10...i want to change for 7

Comment: Do you mean font size?

Comment: yes i mean the font size

Answer (score 0):

Try following. it will work:

```
<mx:TextArea id="mytxtArea"  initialize="mytxtArea_initializeHandler(event)"/>

protected function mytxtArea_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    mytxtArea.htmlText = "This is <font size='30'>html</font> text";
}
```